# Select by date doesn't seem to work

Tags: mysql

As I am not the world's greatest SQLer, I am working up to something big, step by step.

I have a table:

```
mysql> describe taps;
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag_id        | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| time_stamp    | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| event_id      | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| event_station | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| device_id     | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| device_type   | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And would like to select all entries for a given date (today, 12th Feb, '17).

I am trying

```
mysql> select * from taps WHERE (event_id=4) 
          AND ((time_stamp >= 1486857600000) AND (time_stamp <= 1486944000000));
```

Empty set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

IMPORTANT:  I have simplified things, because I want to compare with variables, which have values which I have obtained from another table, which are also of type `timestamp`.

Hmmm, warnings ....

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                    |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1486857600000' for column 'time_stamp' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1486944000000' for column 'time_stamp' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, I tried casting

```
select * from taps WHERE (event_id=4) 
   AND ((time_stamp >= CAST(1486857600000 AS DATETIME)) 
   AND (time_stamp <= CAST(1486944000000 AS DATETIME)));
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Which I don't understand, as I am the table does have some entries today.

```
mysql> select * from taps order by time_stamp limit 3;
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
| tag_id | time_stamp          | event_id | event_station | device_id | device_type |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
|     44 | 2017-02-12 15:10:25 |     NULL |            16 | NULL      | NULL        |
|     37 | 2017-02-12 15:10:27 |     NULL |            14 | NULL      | NULL        |
|     50 | 2017-02-12 15:10:28 |     NULL |            15 | NULL      | NULL        |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrongly? And what should my query be?

Comment: Can't you use `time_stamp > cast('2017-02-12' as datetime)`?

Comment: The values are variable, taken from another table. Those hard coded values are just for example.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has very confusing terminology for date/time stuff (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)).  A `timestamp` is essentially a datetime with a timezone, because the value is stored as UTC, but reported in the local timezone.

This timestamp is not to be confused with a Unix Timestamp, which is just the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 (or in some cases milliseconds).

In your case, try this:

```
select t.*
from taps t 
where event_id = 4 and
      time_stamp >= '2017-02-11 07:00:00' and
      time_stamp < '2017-02-12 07:00:00';
```

You *could* use `from_unixtimestamp()`.  However, people generally find date formats much easier to read.

Note:  I changed the last condition to a strict inequality.  This gives you 24 hours with no duplication of time, in case something happens at exactly 2017-02-12 07:00:00.

Comment: I  have simplified things, because I want to compare with variables, which have values which I have obtained from another table, which are also of type timestamp

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, literal TIMESTAMP values are normally supplied as strings, in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`. MySQL does allow some latitude in the actual format. More recent versions of MySQL allow for fractional seconds. See the MySQL Reference Manual for a more complete description.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

As an example, MySQL would recognize any of these:

```
'2017-02-12 09:30:45'
'17-02-12 09:30:45'
170212093045
```

---

If we have a requirement to supply/specify literal values that represent integer milliseconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00', we can use a SQL expression to convert those to values that can be compared to `TIMESTAMP`. As a demonstration:

```
 SELECT '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL 1486857600000 / 1000 SECOND AS ts
```

If we need to supply integer millisecond values as a literal in a condition in a WHERE clause, then we can use expressions like the one above.

The query in the question could do something like this to compare the value in a TIMESTAMP column

```
 AND time_stamp >= '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL 1486857600000 / 1000 SECOND 
 AND time_stamp <  '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL 1486944000000 / 1000 SECOND
```